# How to pause Postgres before taking an LVM/ZFS snapshot?

Tags: linux, postgresql, lvm, zfs, zfsonlinux

How can I instruct Postgres to complete all "in-progress" transactions, but to delay starting new ones (without kicking clients off) until I have taken a ZFS or LVM snapshot (which takes less than a second).

e.g.

1. pause Postgres, waiting for "in-progress" transactions to complete
2. sync to disk
3. take ZFS/LVM snapshot
4. resume Postgres

Comment: And why would you need this. Why not just take a snapshot. Yes, the DB state will be dirty, and some of the transactions will be rolled back, but nothing really harmful usually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44260/postgresql-freeze-unfreeze-command-equivalents) on dba.stackexchange seems to be what you are after.

Comments do not seem to automatically link in the side bar (inside the network), so I need to write some more stuff to prevent auto-conversion to a comment... yeah.

Answer (score 1):

The post mentioned in @user121391 answer is correct, but in short:

- You cannot *pause* postgresql in any way (force it to continue open transactions and not process new transactions)
- If the underlying snapshot is atomic (ZFS snapshots seems to be atomic), It's not necessary to do anything before snapshot, If you run a new  `postgres` process on the snapshot, the database will start in recovery mode (as when the previous process stopped abnormally).
- `pg_start_backup` will make recovery process a little faster (since a checkpoint is made, and there will be less pending writes in WAL)